# can't sending the email using javamail in web services

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-mail

Here I have created a web service for user registration, after done with saving data I need to send an e-mail to registered E-mail ID for that i have written a separate class Called SendEmail N calling the method to sendMail(),but when this method is called it gives the classNotFoundException. The Stack trace of the exception is:

```
Feb 19, 2013 12:15:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [/GKWebServer] threw exception [com.sun.jersey.api.container.MappableContainerException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at webServices.UserSevices.insertUser(UserSevices.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:156)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the java mail jar in your classpath.

It can be downloaded from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Or you can add a maven dependency for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure it is included in the war (under `WEB-INF/lib`). Or you might add it to the lib directory of your application server. I prefer not to mess around with the app server though, since you will have to remember all the little bits of manual configuration changes every time you upgrade, and it will have to be replicated in all your environments (e.g. development, test, production).

Comment: Thanks @Steinar, but I have done with this.i.e added the mail.jar file to classpath and my standalone class with public static void main() method can send the mail,but when I'm trying to call this same stub with another name i.e sendMail() then it rises the above exception. Thanks again for quick reply......

Comment: Well... this is a classpath issue. Your application server cannot find the class `javax.mail.MessagingException`, which is included in the javax mail jar. So, this jar is not visible to your application server. Have you checked that it is included with your web application (the war file)?